# Mantener una sesion en Java con jsf y ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Iniciando con Java EE y JSF, necesito crear un login simple y mantener el id y nick del usuario en la sesión.

Para eso cree una clase

```
package Controlador;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

private int usuarioId;

private String usuarioNick;



public SessionBean() {
    super();
}...
```

Desde otra clase intento guardar datos en ella, pero cuando intento acceder retorna `Null pointer exception`.

```
@ManagedBean
b@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioSessionBean {

@EJB
private UsuarioSessionDAO usuarioSession;

@ManagedProperty("#{sessionBean}")
private SessionBean sessionBean;

public void setSessionBean(SessionBean sb){
    if(sb != null){
        this.sessionBean = sb;
    }
}   
...

public String Login(){

    Usuario usr = usuarioSession.Login(usuario.getNick(),   usuario.getPass());
    if(usr != null){
        sessionBean.setUsuarioId(usr.getId());
        sessionBean.setUsuarioNick(usr.getNick());
        return "loginOk";
    }
    return "loginNo";
}
```

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? o mejor dicho ¿cuál sería la forma de crear un simple login?

Comment: No he hecho un manejo de sesion con managed property y no puedo asegurar que lo que esta puesto esta mal, pero lo que se y se recomienda para el manejo de sesion es usar FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap(); Lo anterior devuelve un map de sesion en el que usando clave valor se pueden guardar objetos a traves de sesion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Es mucho más recomendado usar beans manejados por CDI que por JSF. Ahora, el uso de `@ManagedBean` no está aconsejado. Su reemplazo es `@Named` que indica que es un **CDI bean**. Es importante **no mezclar ManagedBeans con scopes CDI** porque simplemente no funcionará y tendrás problemas en tiempo de ejecución.

   ```
   import javax.inject.Named;
   import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; // importante
   @Named
   @SessionScope
   public class SessionBean implements Serializable { ... }
   ```
2. Toda clase que será pasivada (serializada y guardada en el disco duro), como es el caso de los backing beans que tienen scopes **ViewScoped, SessionScoped, FlowScoped, ConversationScoped, ApplicationScoped** deben ser serializables porque CDI son serializados. Tu clase `UsuarioSessionBean` no es serializable.

   ```
   @Named
   @SessionScoped
   public class UsuarioSessionBean implements Serializable { ... }
   ```
3. Elige el scope (ámbito, alcance) de tus backing beans de forma correcta. Si tienes muchos beans en sesión la aplicación perderá rendimiento, porque en cada respuesta envías todos esos beans.

Por ejemplo, puedes crear una clase utilitaria que te permita obtener y añadir valores a la sesión.

```
public class SessionUtils implements Serializable {

    public void add(String key, Object value) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getSessionMap().put(key, value);
    }

    public void get(String key) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getSessionMap().get(key);
    }
}
```

Y no necesitas `UsuarioSessionBean`, tan solo un controlador del login que inyecte `SessionUtils`.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

   @Inject // inyectamos la dependencia
   private SessionUtils session;
   private String username;
   private String password;

   public String login() {
      // comprobar credenciales
      if(exito) {
          // añades el usuario a sesión
          sessionUtils.add("usuarioLogueado", usuario);
          return "home";
      }
      FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Acceso denegado", "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta");
      // como mensaje global
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
      return null; // retorna al mismo login
   }

   // getters y setters
}
```

#### ACTUALIZACIÓN

En la aplicación para Android de StackExchange me apareció como "activa", ahora he visto la fecha y es de **mayo**. Disculpen por el lío.

Comment: Gracias por el voto negativo

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, el problema ya lo resolví, pero tus notas van a servir para aprender cosas nuevas.

Comment: Gracias por la selección. Un saludo colega.

Answer (score 2):

Yo he realizado un login con la API de Google Oauth2 es lo mismo que quieres hacer pero en vez de pasar una variables Session, tendrás que pasar dos variables "*login*" y "*password*"

**login.xhtml**

```
        <h:commandLink action="#{loginBean.sessGmail()}" ajax="false" type="submit">
            <h:graphicImage library="resources" name="images/iconGmailBlack.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; "/>
                                <f:param name="idParamtro" value="#{loginBean.Login}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
....
    private Session Login;

    public Session getLogin() {
        return Login;
    }

    public void setLogin(Session userLog) {
        this.userLog = Login;
    }
....
```

**MainLogin.java**

```
.....
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainBean {


    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean userLogin;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

            /** Se carga el Login en una variable de MainBean*/
            "variableMainBean" = userLogin.getLogin();
   ...}
...}
```

Además tienes que configurar los filtros de la aplicación para no poder acceder a una URL de la aplicación directamente.

Esto es para que te hagas una idea de la estructura de llamadas para hacer el login. Hay infinitas formas de hacer el login ya que puedes meter API de terceros como la que usado yo para realizar el login, ademas de hacer todo tipo de comprobaciones con bbdd, etc.

Si te ayuda hay varios tutoriales (Español) en youtube para ver directamente las diferentes formas que los puedes hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregarlo al mapa de sessiones

ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
context.getSessionMap().put(key, "")

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas con cuidado [answer] y de paso hagas el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una respuesta ***CORRECTA***, pues las respuestas que solo contienen código sin explicaciones no sirven de mucho para *aprender*, solo sirven para copiar y pegar... Si han hecho una pregunta, tal vez sea porque no tienen mucha experiencia con lo que preguntan, no crees que una explicación seguro que ayudaría a entenderlo mejor? :)